# Routing is not working in my web application when I refresh the page in the browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, routes

When I type http://localhost:8000 in the browser, it is redirecting to http://localhost:8000/home. This is working fine as per code. When I refresh the page with same http://localhost:8000/home getting 404 error. Can anyone help me why this is happening and correct me.

app.js

```
var myapp=angular
            .module("demo",['ngRoute'])
            .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
              $routeProvider
              .when('/home',{
                templateUrl:'Templates/home.html',
                controller:'homeController'
              })
              .when('/about', {
                templateUrl:'Templates/about.html',
                controller:'aboutController'
              })
              .when('/contact',{
                templateUrl:'Templates/contact.html',
                controller:'contactController'
              })

              .otherwise({
               redirectTo: '/home'
               })
              $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
            });
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="demo">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
     <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
     <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
     <script src="rest-controller.component.js"></script>
     <script src="Controllers/contact.js"></script>
     <script src="Controllers/about.js"></script>
     <script src="Controllers/home.js"></script>
     <base href="/">
</head>
<body>
   <ol>
    <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ol>
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

home.js (controller file)

```
 angular.module('demo').controller("homeController", function($scope){
   $scope.hello ="home";
  });
```

about.js

```
angular.module('demo').controller("aboutController", function($scope){
  $scope.tap="About Me";
 });
```

contact.js

```
angular.module('demo').controller("contactController", function($scope){
 $scope.message="hello";
});
```

Comment: Is the 404 error served by the server?

Comment: You can't arbitrarily use html5Mode without configuring server. Your server knows nothing about the virtual directories that are being used. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: The server also has to be configured. The way it works now, is the site loads from the server on the initial request. When you change the route, that is done client-side. Then if you refresh the page, it asks for the new route from the server, yet the server doesn't know about it.

Comment: Yes, it is comming from server only @Arun Ghosh

Comment: @sir what your application server stack?

Comment: I am running the application with node @Arun Ghosh

Comment: @sri can you share the nodejs routing code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try disabling html5 mode?

```
// $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Comment: @sri: After disable go to http://localhost:8000  and when to click home it should take to http://localhost:8000/#/home. Is the # coming?

Comment: After disable html5 mode then I enter the  localhost:8000 in browser, It redirecting to localhost:8000/#/home. This is working

Comment: I used ui-router instead of ng-router then it is working fine. Now I can see the exact view respective to the url whenever you refresh the page.